# VBA Excel copy-paste from workbook to another workbook transpose values and different ranges

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

The input data are always columns in 7 different sheets that need to be output in different columns across different non-in-sequence rows

```
Q2_1    Q3_1    Q4_1
13      17      11
4        2       5
3        2       4
2        2       4
6        5       4
```

The sequence of the rows (output) is 5, 10, 15, 23, 28, 33, 38, 43, 48, 53, 61, 66, 71, 79, 84, 89, 94, 102, 107, 112, 117, 122, 128, 135, 140, 148, 153, 158, 166, 171, 179, 184, 189, 194

And the Columns are from i5 to M5 for Q2_1, i10 to M10 for Q3

I have tried 2 fors and 2 do loops, with no luck. Is there any way to use arrays?

I am very to programming.

```
Sub CPRelative()

    Dim n As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim itotal As Integer

    Windows("book1.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets(3).Select

    For n = 2 To 35
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(4, n), Cells(8, n)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Windows("book2.xlsm").Activate


         For i = 5 To 194

            Select Case i
            Case 5, 10, 15, 23, 28, 33, 38, 43, 48, 53, 61, 66, 71, 79, 84, 89, 94, 102, 107, 112, 117, 122, 128, 135, 140, 148, 153, 158, 166, 171, 179, 184, 189, 194

                ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 9), Cells(i, 13)).Select
               Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
            End Select
        Next n
End Sub
```

And do until and do while

```
Sub NestedLoop()
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Windows("book1.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets(3).Select

    n = 2
    Do Until ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(4, n), Cells(8, n)).Value = ("8,n")

        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(4, n), Cells(8, n)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Windows("book2.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets(1).Select

        'i = 5

        Do While ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 9), Cells(i, 13)).Value = ""
            Select Case i
            Case 5, 10, 15, 23, 28, 33, 38, 43, 48, 53, 61, 66, 71, 79, 84, 89, 94, 102, 107, 112, 117, 122, 128, 135, 140, 148, 153, 158, 166, 171, 179, 184, 189, 194
               ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 9), Cells(i, 13)).Select
               Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
           End Select

           i = i + 1
       Loop
       n = n + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: "Is there any way to use arrays?" yep, [you can use arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/array-function), and [here's how you transpose them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-transpose-method-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding before and after screenshots will lead to quicker responses and better answers.

Here is a video from my favorite VBA Excel video series that you must watch: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&t=3123s&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

### Source

[image]

### Target

[image]

```
Sub CPRelative2()
    Dim n As Long, r As Long
    Dim arrRows As Variant
    Dim Source As Range, Target As Range
    Set Source = Workbooks("180610_SequencingScenarioTEST1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells
    Set Target = Workbooks("180610_TestSurveyAnalysisTest1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells

    arrRows = Array(5, 10, 15, 23, 28, 33, 38, 43, 48, 53, 61, 66, 71, 79, 84, 89, 94, 102, 107, 112, 117, 122, 128, 135, 140, 148, 153, 158, 166, 171, 179, 184, 189, 194)
    For n = 2 To 35
         r = arrRows(n - 2)
        Target.Cells(r, "I").Resize(1, 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Source.Cells(4, n).Resize(5, 1).Value)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Forever grateful....This code looks very nice with the arrays... tomorrow morning I’ll try and update you... would you kindly recommend any other resources to learn VBA ? I found vba is fun in YouTube ... I am looking for well structured methodology to develop from small subroutine to more complex ones... and showing the most practical object is class properties etc,,, and tricks of the trace ....

Comment: Didn’t try it yet as my laptop not with me at this very moment....however ....The target should like this: i5 j5 k5 l5 m5 with the data coming from the source B4 B5 B6 B7 B8.... then again from the source c4 c5 c6 c7 C8 copy paste to the target i10 to M10,

Comment: I am glad to hear that.  appy Coding!

Comment: if u allow me to ask... the n-2 in the array...it is positioning correctly...and it is saying that the 5th row is the starting point like zero level,,,isnt it ?

Comment: Yes! `arrRows` is a zero based array.  `n` is by to `n = 2`.  So I `n - 2` syncs the array indices to the `n` counter.

Comment: and and the resize...it is because the from a column needs it to be converted to a row ...though thought that with transpose that would have been solved...

Comment: `Resize` resizes the range object.  `Range("A1").Resize(1,5)` is the same as saying `Range("A1:E1")`  and `Range("A1").Resize(5,1)` is equivalent to `Range("A1:A5")`  or `Range(Range("A1") ,Range("A5")).  Using  `Resize`  and `Offset` can really simplify the code

Comment: is this the same Range(Range("b2") ,Range("b8")) = Range(cells(4,2),Cells(8,2)) e.g?

Comment: `cells(4,2)` should be `cells(2, 2)` to make both parts refer to the same range.

Comment: Hello Tinman do you mind to take a look to the new question I posted just now... Thanks in advance